# How to use multiple palettegen arguments in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I am creating a palette with FFMPEG using the following:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mov -vf palettegen=max_colors=5 palette.gif
```

I want to use additional features such as *reserve_transparent* as mentioned in the [FFMPEG palettegen docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen-1), but having trouble getting it to work:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mov -vf palettegen=max_colors=5,reserve_transparent=1 palette.gif
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options for a filter are separated by a colon, so

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mov -vf palettegen=max_colors=5:reserve_transparent=1 palette.gif
```